# How to understand void (*action)(struct softirq_action *)

Tags: c

This is soft interrupt in Linux kernel. How to understand the definition `void (*action)(struct softirq_action *);`?

```
struct softirq_action
{
    void (*action)(struct softirq_action *);
};
```

Comment: [This](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*action%29%28struct+softirq_action+*%29)

Comment: Start with understanding why this is a declaration, not a definition. Next check your C book, chapter Pointer -> Function Pointer.

Comment: if you are not sure you can check here: cdecl.org

Answer (score 4):

Start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering the following rules:

```
T *a[N];   // a is an array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N]; // a is a pointer to an array of T
T *f();    // f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();  // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

So:

```
       action                                -- action
      *action                                -- is a pointer to
     (*action)(                       )      -- a function taking
     (*action)(                       )      --   unnamed parameter
     (*action)(                      *)      --   is a pointer to
     (*action)(struct softirq_action *)      --   struct softirq_action
void (*action)(struct softirq_action *);     -- and returning void
```

Answer (score 0):

declare action as pointer to function (taking pointer to struct softirq_action as it's only parameter) returning void

Comment: If you agree with the answer you should accept it and/or upvote it (click the up arrow on the left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

as the answers said: this is a declaration not a definition.
How to understand it ? you can follow these steps:
1- start with the identifier followed by the asterix which is "action", as it is preceded by asterix so it is a pointer 
2- if it is enclosed in brackets, it is a pointer to function.
3- read the items before the pointer name, this is the return type
4- read the items after the pointer name, this is the function parameters.

so to summarize: **action is a pointer to function that return void & take a pointer to structure as a parameter.**

Answer (score 0):

It is a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) variable (called action) which can point to any function with a `struct softirq_action *` parameter and a `void` return value.

For example if you have this function:

```
void IRQ_handler(struct softirq_action *);
```

then you can give its address to the pointer like

```
action = &IRQ_handler;
```

and call it like

```
action(action_struct);
```

With a function pointer you can determine in runtime which function to call.